# While creating folder in sharepoint using C# takes much time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, client-object-model

Yesterday I have programmed to create folder in SharePoint 2010 using C#. It's fine that code create folder but the problem is that while creating a folder it takes 5-10 seconds. And i think it's too much. Because if i have thousands of folders to create then folder creation time would be significantly large. So how could i solve this issue?

Comment: Could you post your code, so we can try to advice what to change? Also, instantiating an SPSite or SPWeb object, can take several seconds, indeed, but you need to do it only once, not for every folder you want to create. So creating 1000 folders could take less than creating 1 folder multiplied by 1000.

Comment: First of all I would like to speak about the folder, the folder  was created in the Document Library with a custom Content ype . The custom content has 2-3 lookup fields, and around 15-20 fields in total.
Actually, in our architecture we have a command system to  create a folder , means whenever a folder create option encounter then we create a command for that folder to create. Thereafter we pass that command to “WCF” where SPWeb object is initialized and disposed each time a command is received. So in this scenario how would I improve folder creation time.

Comment: In this case, why are you worried about the time needed to create 1000 folders? If I understood you correctly, if somebody places a command for a folder a web service will eventually create it. If you worry about the scenario when 1000 simultaneous requests come in and then the WCF web service would have to create 1000 folders in the same time, then I would suggest to think about a queue mechanism at the web service level, which could reuse the same SPWeb object for the same site.